# boxplot in R is howing a vertical straight line

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I have a data frame of multiple columns. I want to create a two boxplots of the two variable "secretary" and "driver" but the result is not satisfiying as the picture shows [boxplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BgpnF.png). This is my code:

```
   profession ve.count.descrition euse.count.description Qualitative.result
   secretary   0                      1                      -0.5
   secretary   0                      2                         1
   driver      1                      1                        -1
   driver      0                      2                       0.3

data %>%
  mutate(Qualitative.result = factor(Qualitative.result)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Profession , fill = Qualitative.result)) +
  geom_boxplot()
```

Comment: What do you actually want to show with this data?

Comment: I want to have two boxplots and not a two staight lines

Comment: You need to use data for x and y. Now you are only using x which results in a straight line.

Comment: You are trying to plot the 'distribution' of Profession which is a discrete variable, so the resulting boxplots don't have any width. What do you exactly want to see with these boxplots?

Comment: I want to see where the profession is distributed the most in the continious variable Qualitative.result

Answer (score 0):

You should not make Qualitative.result as `factor`. Maybe you want something like this:

```
library(tidyverse)
data %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Profession, y = Qualitative.result, fill = Profession)) +
  geom_boxplot()
```

Output:

[image]